# how to add attribute in search results?

Tags: dropdown-attribute

I have set some custom attributes (with dropdown). This code works in grid + product view:

```
$_Promo =  $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('promos'));

switch ($_Promo) {
case 0:

    break;
case 4:
            echo '<div class="promoBF2">3 x 2</div>';
    break;
case 5:
            echo '<div class="promoBF1">3 x 1</div>';
    break;
case 6:
            echo '<div class="promoBF3">2 x 1</div>';
    break;
```

}

I want the attribute to be displayed in search results, found that  mytheme/template/catalogsearch/results.phtml   calls another function: $this->getProductListHtml()

where do I find that function?  Or what is the proper way of adding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the admin of your site, in Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes, edit the attribute you want in search.   In the Frontend Properties area, make sure `Use In Search Results Layered Navigation` is set to true.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't that (double checked, already had it enabled)

Comment: I updated this answer, check that attribute instead of the two I listed originally.

Comment: Have you reindexed since changing the attributes configuration? You may need to reindexed catalog product attributes index.