# Search (elasticsearch) on 2.4 returns no result for 2 or more search terms

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

For example, I if search for "Lord of the Rings", I will get no results, but if search just "Lord", or "Rings", I will get the results.

Can't locate what could be the issue.

Update, I finally got the expection out:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: field:[sku] was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery",
        "index_uuid": "znhJmQSgS4C07uL1bTJ_bw",
        "index": "magento2_product_1_v8"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "magento2_product_1_v8",
        "node": "AS3yhH-9SP-3qRZ6Pytg3g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: field:[sku] was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery",
          "index_uuid": "znhJmQSgS4C07uL1bTJ_bw",
          "index": "magento2_product_1_v8",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason": "field:[sku] was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix it. If you have some custom attributes in catalog, you should include them in the search so they can be properly indexed.

Comment: Can you explain more about this issue? Because I am facing the same issue in my project.

Comment: As I said,  I have a custom attribute (in my case its `sku`) and that attribute wasn't included in the search. Check here how to include attribute in the seach: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90043/82810

Comment: Thank you, bro my issue is resolved.

Comment: @Zdravko `sku` isn't really a custom attribute though, and you can't remove this attribute from search in the first place, so I'm unsure how you managed to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of these commands? "bin/magento indexer:reindex" or "bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext"

Comment: I did, I needed to do that in the first place.